# Tab bar image not displayed

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have this problem. I have a tabbar created in appDelegate:

```
RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
```

[other controllers initialized...]

```
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNavigationController,secondController,thirdController, nil];
```

Now when in RootViewController I try to assign an image to the tabBar:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabRoot.png"];
    self.tabBarItem.title = @"Root";
}
```

But nothing is displayed, why? The strange thing is that if I do the same thing but without the navigationController, the image is correctly displayed.

Comment: Add image for tabbarItem in appDelegate..

Comment: put break point and check ? i have checked its working fine .

Comment: Yes I have checked, the tabbar title and image are assigned but not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabRoot.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabRoot.png"]];
```